# TFS 2008 to Visual Studio Team Services Migration

Tags: tfs, version-control, azure-devops

I'm looking to upgrade our internal source control from the archaic TFS 2008 on prem, to the nice shiny VSTS (was Visual Studio Online) however it really doesn't simple a simple process. I tried using OpsHub but it looks like TFS 2010 is the earliest supported there.

I'd be happy just manually copying code but I don't know of a way to maintain branch relationships once those branches have been put in to VSTS.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to upgrade/move my code?

I'd be happy with an answer that explains how to maintain relationships when copying branches from one version to the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this tool: [TFS Integration Platform](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/).

Comment: It's not brilliant but it seems to do the trick for some of my projects, thanks